# deleting a character with backspace key

Tags: javascript, svg

I am using an SVG rectangle to simulate a text input, and another one for a submit button. A click on the button will alert what a user have typed. I would like to be able to delete content when backspace is pressed, and have ran into trouble.

Here's the code:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<script><![CDATA[
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"

// when a key is pressed call function keypress but first check and see that the       
document.documentElement.setAttribute("onkeypress","keypress(evt)")
attention=false; function doit(){attention=true;}

//typing
function keypress(evt){
//declaring variables
newtext=String.fromCharCode(evt.charCode)
text=document.getElementById("inputText")
count=text.textContent.length

 if (attention == true){
  if (count<13){
    text.textContent += newtext 
    }

  }
}

//alert what user typed
function ntext(){
 var textValue = document.getElementById('inputText').textContent
 alert(textValue + " <-- This is what you typed")
}

//trying to get backspace to delete character
document.onkeydown = backspace;  
function backspace()
{

   var KeyID = event.keyCode;
   switch(KeyID)
   {
      case 8:
      alert("backspace isnt working wahh :/")
      text.textContent += newtext.substr(0,newtext.length-1)
      break; 
      case 46:
      alert("Delete")
      break;
      default:
      break;
   }
}
]]>
</script>

<g>
<rect onclick="doit()" width="115" height="25" x="20" y="20" 
style="fill:white;stroke-width:2;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
<text id="inputText"  font-size="15" x="22" y="37"></text>
</g>

<g onclick="ntext()">
<rect  x="140" y="18" height="30" width="60"
          rx="10" ry="10"
          style="stroke:#787878; fill: #D0D0D0  "/>
          <text font-size="12"  x="150" y="37" >Submit</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Here it is on a [live webpage](http://granite.sru.edu/~jaw1005/input.svg).

The backspace event is evidently caught, as pressing the backspace triggers the alert.

I have tried many things, all to no avail. How to resolve this?

#### Notes

- Please don't offer the use of jQuery
- At the moment, it only works in IE

Comment: i don't get it - backspace triggers correctly, so it's the *working* part of your code, but the text input is not working. please be clearer about the problem: what is *expected* to happen, and what *actually* happens instead?

Comment: Can't you use an input element instead?

Comment: If I could use an input element I would... And yes the backspace is being triggered correctly. Once it's triggered I would like to delete characters from with in my makeshift text input area.